# $location and window.location Comparison

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Which one is better to use in angularjs, `$location` or `window.location`.

For example , We can use `$location.path()` or `window.location.href` for the same work. Which is more suitable ?

Can anyone suggest that ?

Comment: `$location` is **angularjs** wrapper for window.location. As **angularJS** heavily rely on it's change detection technique to make changes available to UI. Angular does this by running digest cycle on every change you make to angular objects like $scope and others.  

If you use window.location directly, angular won't be able to detect change at that moment. Hence they use $location, which internally uses window.location and calls the digest cycle.

This way location changes are updated instantaneously.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `$location`, so that AngularJS is aware of the changes you're making. If you directly manipulate `window.location`, AngularJS won't recognize it, and changes won't occur until next digest cycle is invoked by some other AngularJS method. In fact this is one reason AngularJS has wrappers around native methods, like `$timeout`, `$interval` etc

Answer (score 0):

For Location in your angularjs  app route  Use `$location.path("yourroute");`  or `$location.url('/RouteTo/');`

For locations outside of the Angular app (ie no route defined), plain old JavaScript will serve:

`window.location = "http://www.domain.com/login"`